# arcpy.da.SearchCursor keeps running, without any response or error

Tags: arcmap, cursor

I am using 'arcpy.da.SearchCursor' in Python script for ArcGIS 10.5, while the script is always keeping running, without any result and error. I use print to see where the problem is; it seems that 'arcpy.da.SearchCursor' cannot be finished, as it does not print 2. However, this works well if I use these syntaxes in the Python window of ArcMap.

Here is the code:

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\\Users\hsdfyan1\Desktop\add_point_attributes\Feb_8_1_e_pth_split_join.shp'
fileds = ['time_first', 'time_last', 'SHAPE@']
print(1)
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fileds)
print(2)
for row in cursor:
    print(row[0],row[1])
```

The only result is 1

Comment: Yes, digit 1. If I type these syntaxes one by one at Arcgis IDLE, it can also get the right result, while no result if I use python script

Comment: The proper syntax for a DA Cursor is to use the `with` construct (so it removes the read lock when you're done with it)

Comment: I tried it, while it does not work

Comment: What are you trying to do with `print(1)` and `print(2)`?

Comment: I want to see where the program is running and where the problem is

Comment: Does `arcpy.Exists(fc) is True` say `True`?

Comment: I guess it is not the problem of syntaxes. All syntaxes about arcpy do not work suddenly but without any error somehow. it is very wired, all my scripts that work before cannot get results.